# Groovy collect returning GString in a Jenkins Workflow script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-workflow

It seems that in the following piece of code:

```
def formattedPaths = affectedFiles.collect {
    "${it.editType.name} ${it.path}"
}
```

at least sometimes `formattedPaths` evaluates to a GString instead of a List. This piece of code is a fragment of a larger Jenkins Workflow script, something like:

```
node {
     currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets[0].collect { 
         """<b>${it.user}</b> @ rev. ${it.revision}: ${it.msg}
         ${affectedFilesLog(it.affectedFiles)}"""
     }
}

def affectedFilesLog(affectedFiles) {
    println "Affected files [${affectedFiles.class}]: $affectedFiles"
    def formattedPaths = affectedFiles.collect {
        "${it.editType.name} ${it.path}"
    }

    println "formattedPaths [${formattedPaths.class}]: $formattedPaths"
    formatItemList(formattedPaths)
}

def formatItemList(list) {
    if (list) {
        return list.join('\n')
    }

    return  '(none)'
}
```

Running this script in Jenkins produces output:

```
Running: Print Message
Affected files [class java.util.ArrayList]: [hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet$Path@5030a7d8]
Running: Print Message
formattedPaths [class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl]: edit my/path/flow.groovy
(...)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.join() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [
]
```

And this makes me believe that in the code:

```
println "Affected files [${affectedFiles.class}]: $affectedFiles"
def formattedPaths = affectedFiles.collect {
    "${it.editType.name} ${it.path}"
}

println "formattedPaths [${formattedPaths.class}]: $formattedPaths"
```

`affectedFiles` is `ArrayList` (script output `Affected files [class java.util.ArrayList]: [hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogSet$Path@5030a7d8]` in the output)

but result of running collect method on it - assigned to `formattedPaths` - is a GString (output: `formattedPaths [class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl]: edit my/path/flow.groovy`)

Shouldn't the collect method always return a List?

Comment: Yes, it should always produce a List.  I suspect something else may be happening here...  Why does it say `Running: Print Message` twice?  Is this running with multiple threads?  I suspect the second thread may be crashing, but you're looking at the printout of the first thread...

Comment: I guess the first message is  for println "Affected files [${affectedFiles.class}]: $affectedFiles" and second is for println "formattedPaths [${formattedPaths.class}]: $formattedPaths"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the discussion in the comments pointing that it may be some side effects done by the Jenkins Workflow plugin, I decided to use a plain for-each loop:

```
def affectedFilesLog(affectedFiles) {
    println "Affected files [${affectedFiles.class}]: $affectedFiles"

    def ret = ""
    for (Object affectedFile : affectedFiles) {
        ret += affectedFile.path + '\n'
    }

    println("affectedFilesLog ret [${ret.class}]: $ret")
    if (!ret) {
        return '(brak)'
    }

    return ret;
}
```

EDIT 19/11/2015:
Jenkins workflow plugin mishandles functions taking Closures, see https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481 and its duplicates. So rewriting the code to a plain Java for-each loop was the best solution.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Moving away from collect method and closure to indexed for loop solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently use the `collect` method. [JENKINS-26481](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26481)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your code is not thread safe. If you pass some objects as paramters to some other functions, do not change this. Always create and return a new changed object. Do not manipulate the original data. You should check where your objects live. Is it just inside a function or in global scope?

Comment: Will be formattedPaths used somewhere else? Your code seems correct. It should work. Maybe there are some sideeffects?

Comment: Yes, they are used in a body of a notification e-mail. Ok thanks, I will probably iterate using the for each loop rather than using the collect method

Comment: I think, that collect method is not a problem. It allway return ArrayList. You can try it here https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ with different object. I guess formattedPaths can be overwritten by some sideeffects after you make collect but before it will be printed.

Comment: You can try to use explicit type List formattedPaths = ... So it cann't be overwritten with GString, you will get an error and you will see which function tries to do this in the stacktrace.

Comment: it's possible that there are some side effects done by the jenkins workflow plugin, which executes the script. I have changed the code to use a plain for each loop and it works. Thank you